# Is there any benefit (semantic or other) to using a static method that calls a constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, static-methods

I just updated Visual Studio 2013 and I noticed that in the project template for an MVC application the ApplicationDbContext class now has a static method that just calls the constructor:

```
public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

This seems like clutter to me but I imagine that there is some semantic reason that I should now start using `ApplicationDbContext.Create()` instead of `new ApplicationDbContext()`. Are there any benefits to doing so?

Comment: This seems like a poor implementation of a factory.

Comment: Is the constructor private? ... This is a pattern that is used to stop a consumer from just creating an object without specifying what is required of it - forcing you through a static method. Sure, this one seems useless - but if you want to extend it, the setup is there for you to do so.

Comment: The constructor is not private.

Comment: If you use Autodesks API's they all implement this pattern - but they make the constructors private. For example; `static Pipe Document::CreateNewPipe(...);` and `static Curve Document::CreateNewCurve(...);` honestly I find it incredibly annoying and not useful. However its probably useful to API designers to ensure object cohesion.

Comment: Google the "gang of four" book and read an overview of the design patterns described therein. This is a simple implementation of the factory pattern which, among 22 other design patterns, is described in the book. It's useful to be familiar with them at least to the point of recognizing them and knowing when to use them.

Comment: One obvious benefit which nobody mentioned, the **improving of readability**. You can name the static method whatever you want, to better mention the intention, but constructor's name is fixed. This especially comes in handy when you have multiple constructors overloaded.

Comment: @Tyler I do own a copy of Design Patterns and Factory and Singleton definitely crossed my mind. I should have rephrased my question to ask whether using this exact method has any benefits.

Comment: @Mousa agreed. But what bothere me is the way this stands right now I actually find the static method less readable. I guess I really want to know if  there is any point to this besides pushing you in a certain direction if/when you actually extend the class, which you may never do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually. yes.

In your specific case, wrapping it thusly allows you to quickly start bolting on logic, such as making the ApplicationDbContext and singleton or handling an exception in a common way for the whole application. Since a constructor cannot return null, this can be very important to be able to catch an exception and return null.

[Tuple.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the prime example of generic inference, which does not work with Constructors. This allows you say

```
Tuple.Create(Item1, Item2.. ItemN);
```

And the let the compiler infer types, rather than

```
new Tuple<T1, T2...Tn>(Item1, Item2...ItemN);
```

Which is more verbose, and takes a bit more work if you want to switch out one of those types.

There is also the case of Anonymous types, which cannot be specified explicitly and thus cannot be used in new statements. I have specifically had occasion where, while searching assemblies for a specific Attribute to link a command structure for, I wanted to make an enumerable (a Queue, in this case) out of an anonymous type during the search to pair class references with their constructor and string arguments, rather than looking these up every time they're needed. Since I can again use Generic inference in a method, I was able to wrap the constructor in an extension method and get the job done.

There are also cases for singleton patterns, wherein you want the "GetInstance" method to usually create a value, or get one if it exists. May not qualify since it does slightly more than wrap a constructor.

In addition, there are plenty of cases where you may want to control implementation procedures, such as forcing them onto other threads, logging them in a database to be undone later, or bolting on a permissions system, all of which can be done by making a constructor wrapper and adding a few more lines of logic, and then privatizing the constructor to avoid it being called directly.

There are also cases where I've created a factory method which delegates to known children in order to provide a different implementation of a returned interface or abstract based on provided parameters. This has the added benefit of being able to hide the implementing classes - the Type class and IEnumerable interface make use of this pattern.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Constructor type parameter inference (allowing `new Tuple(1, 2)`) is one of the expected new features in C# 6.

Comment: This is a great answer. One thing I wanted to know, that I did not state clearly, is whether or not there is any reason you would use the static method as it stands right now. If not, I suppose it's only there in case you need it, which seems unnecessary (despite encouraging the use of beneficial patterns) for a project template that becomes more cluttered with every release.

Answer (score 6):

This pattern can be very useful, especially if you use a private constructor, and return an *interface type* from the Create, rather than the concrete type.

```
private ApplicationDbContext()
{

}

public static IApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

Now consumers of your class are prevented from depending on the concrete implementation - they can only rely on the abstraction.

Comment: Commonly, this is referred to as the Factory Method Pattern. http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the constructor with static methods (*creation methods*) allows you to chose a specific name that conveys information. You can also create several methods with the same parameter signature such as `CreateX(float f)` and `CreateY(float f)`, which you cannot do with constructors.

A situation where this is really useful is e.g. for creating structs that represent physical quantities that may have several units, such as time, length or weight. Here, you could use creation methods to force the programmer to always explicitly specify the unit instead of just passing a unit-less number to a single constructor (which assumes a certain unit, and getting it wrong might have [huge consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)).

Example:

```
public struct Length
{
  private const double MetersPerYard = 0.9144;
  private double _meters;

  private Length(double meters)
  {
    _meters = meters;
  }

  public static Length FromMeters(double meters)
  {
    return new Length(meters);
  }

  public static Length FromYards(double yards)
  {
    return new Length(yards*MetersPerYard);
  }

  public double Meters 
  {
    get { return _meters; } 
  }

  public double Yards
  {
    get { return _meters / MetersPerYard; }
  }
}
```

Or take a look at [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and methods like [`FromMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.fromminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`FromSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.fromseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) etc.